# Can you utilize the RasPi 0W ribbon connector side to use as a display cable instead of GPIO pins?

Tags: display

I want to create a tiny device with a display, but I don't know if I can use the side ribbon cable instead of GPIO.

Comment: `display` is not a very good description of a hardware device ... a single LED can be classified as a display

Comment: The ribbon connector can only be used to drive the official display.  It does not give access to the general GPIO.  You need to clarify the question.